# System identification of $Ax = b$

Tags: linear-algebra, system-identification

Given a system of the form $Ax = b$, I have a method to extract infinitely many combinations of $A$ and $b$ that satisfies a given $x$. Can I argue that any combination of $A$ and $b$ (such that $A^{-1}b = x$) satisfies the governing equations that the original system $Ax = b$ represents?

Comment: `any combination of A and b (such that A^-1*b = x) does satisfy the governing equations` That's a stronger than needed condition. For example $A = 0, b = 0$ satisfy the original equation, but can't be written in the form $A^{-1}b = x$.